# Run a web project on virtual environment having Python 3.7 on linux

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.7

I have a linux server having python 2.7 installed. My website is hosted on this server. I had a new script which doesn't support 2.7 . I read about virtual environment in python. Can I create a virtual environment with Python 3.7? Even if I do so how to I make my project run on this virtual environment. I mean when I run my site I go to a link like https://52.192.xx.xx:8080/myWebsite-1.0/
And for the backend I just upload my eclipse project as WAR file to the server at a location .../webapps/ and restart tomcat. I have no idea what other changes I need to make on the python end so that this project runs on python 3.7. I need to know whether I can create a virtual environment having 3.7 and make my project run there.

Comment: All you need to do is have `python3.7` installed with the support of `venv` module. If `venv` module raises an error you may need to install `apt-get install python3-venv`

Comment: virtual environment doesn't means you run virtual machine like in VirtualBox but it creates folder and copy only some parts of python3.7 to this folder so it doesn't uses other modules - and it means that python 3.7 has to be already installed to create this virtual environment.

Comment: maybe ask admins to install Python 3.7 - or at least check if there is no other Python 3.x - like 3.6, 3.5, 3.4